# Botskills connect via Azure CI CD

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, botframework, azure-bot-service

Problem:Create an Azure Bot i.e. Virtual Assistant(VA) and Skill bot for multiple environment (Beta,Prod) via Azure CI CD using a single code base with multiple configuration.

Solutions tried: Had multiple entry of configuration on a single code base created a single WebApp bot and built the CI CD and updated the bot .It works individually when checked on portal.but fails when connected to the application.

Issue: I want the VA bot and the Skill bot to be connected tried to do it via skills.json but it did not work.
We tried using "botkills connect" command but to use it i need to have codebase for Multiple environment (as botskills need to executed on VA bot to connect to particular skill bot) and when tried to connect it connects me to dev skill bot.

We need to use single codebase to deploy BOT(VA & Skill) in multiple environment with multiple configurations wherein we need to connect the VA & Skill bot too.
Everything to be part of Azure CI CD

Comment: I think you're going to need to add a lot more information here. Comments like "_but fails when connected to the application._" and "_It works individually when checked on portal.but fails when connected to the application_" don't really help much. Please lay out more specifics of the steps you've taken, if you are getting errors, etc.